# Does lua perform "require" during compile time?

Tags: import, lua, compilation, runtime, require

When "require" is called in Lua, is the file simply copied into the current file (similar to include "*.h" in C) or is it done by the VM during runtime?

Comment: It is done by the VM during runtime

Answer (score 1):

`require` is not a part of Lua as a language. It's just a function call in Lua's standard library. And all function calls execute at runtime.

After all, `require` doesn't load files; the package system's loaders do. Those loaders can be changed at runtime, and all `require` calls after such changes will reflect them. Some loaders are based on environment variables, whose values can change *between* executions of a Lua program. Each execution of the script, whether pre-compiled or not, will see these changes.